# How is this faster? 52-bit modulo multiply using "FPU trick" faster than inline ASM on x64

Tags: performance, assembly, optimization, x86-64

I have found that this:

```
#define mulmod52(a,b,m) (((a * b) - (((uint64_t)(((double)a * (double)b) / (double)m) - 1ULL) * m)) % m)
```

... is faster than:

```
static inline uint64_t _mulmod(uint64_t a, uint64_t b, uint64_t n) {
    uint64_t d, dummy;                    /* d will get a*b mod c */
    asm ("mulq %3\n\t"              /* mul a*b -> rdx:rax */
         "divq %4\n\t"              /* (a*b)/c -> quot in rax remainder in rdx */
         :"=a"(dummy), "=&d"(d)     /* output */
         :"a"(a), "rm"(b), "rm"(n)  /* input */
         :"cc"                      /* mulq and divq can set conditions */
        );
    return d;
}
```

The former is a trick to exploit the FPU to compute modular multiplication of two up to 52 bit numbers. The latter is simple X64 ASM to compute modular multiplication of two 64 bit numbers, and of course it also works just fine for only 52 bits.

The former is faster than the latter by about 5-15% depending on where I test it.

How is this possible given that the FPU trick also involves one integer multiply and one integer divide (modulus) plus additional FPU work? There's something I'm not understanding here. Is it some weird compiler artifact such as the **asm** inline ruining compiler optimization passes?

Comment: You should check the generated assembly. Also check if any of the operands are known at compile time. Post [mcve] of the actual code you measured.

Comment: Isn't that a `double` divide?  That's significantly faster than 64-bit integer divide on Skylake, for example.  (Especially throughput.)  [Floating point division vs floating point multiplication](//stackoverflow.com/a/45899202) and  [Trial-division code runs 2x faster as 32-bit on Windows than 64-bit on Linux](//stackoverflow.com/a/52558274)

Comment: Modulus implies division, so both have an integer divide.

Comment: Except if the compiler figures it's a compile time constant and gets rid of the division, which your hand written assembly can't do.

Comment: In any case it's a different sort of divide: `divq` acts very differently depending on if the high half of the dividend (so `rdx`) is zero or not.

Comment: @harold I think that's probably the answer then... didn't know that the same instruction behaved differently depending on rdx.

Comment: Oh, I didn't scroll the code block to the right!  (scroll bars are hard to see with the Dark Reader overrides :/)I I missed that there was also a `uint64_t` `%m`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On pre-Icelake processors, such as [Skylake](http://users.atw.hu/instlatx64/GenuineIntel/GenuineIntel0050654_SkylakeXeon9_InstLatX64.txt), there is a big difference between a "full" 128bit-by-64bit division and a "half" 64bit-by-64bit division (where the upper qword is zero). The full one can take up to nearly 100 cycles (varies a bit depending on the value in `rdx`, but there is a sudden "cliff" when `rdx` is even set to 1), the half one is more around 30 to 40-ish cycles depending on the µarch.

The 64bit floating point division is (for a division) relatively fast at around 14 to 20 cycles depending on the µarch, so even with that and some other even-less-significant overhead thrown in, that's not enough to waste the 60 cycle advantage that the "half" division has compared to the "full" division. So the complicated floating point version can come out ahead.

[Icelake](http://users.atw.hu/instlatx64/GenuineIntel/GenuineIntel00706E5_IceLakeY_InstLatX64.txt) apparently has an amazing divider that can do a full division in 18 cycles (and a "half" division isn't faster), the inline asm should be good on Icelake.

On AMD Ryzen, divisions with a non-zero upper qword seem to get slower more gradually as `rdx` gets higher (less of a "perf cliff").

Comment: Hmm... sounds like the FPU trick would still be as fast or faster even on Icelake. It also has the bonus of being relatively portable... works fine on ARM at least and is *way* faster there as ARM lacks X64's 128-bit integer division idiom (AFAIK).

Comment: @AdamIerymenko the FPU trick shouldn't be faster on Icelake, because this time you really *can* argue that they both have a `divq` and it's equally fast both times, but the FPU trick has more overhead. BTW if the performance of this function is important, usually the same modulus is used a lot, and in that case you might prefer a [Barrett reduction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barrett_reduction) or related trickery

Comment: https://www.uops.info/html-tp/SKL/DIV_R64-Measurements.html also has Skylake `div r64` throughput and uop measurements for slow vs. fast.  Even an RDX=0 "fast" `div r64` is still much slower than `div r32`; unlike AMD, the same operands zero-extended to 128-bit / 64-bit divide much slower than 64-bit / 32-bit (for inputs / outputs that fit).  `div r32` is not data-dependent and always [faster on SKL](https://www.uops.info/html-tp/SKL/DIV_R32-Measurements.html) than the "fast division" RDX=0 case for `div r64`.  Microcoded as many more unavoidable uops.

Comment: See also [Trial-division code runs 2x faster as 32-bit on Windows than 64-bit on Linux](//stackoverflow.com/a/52558274).  So if you can manage it, *definitely* use 32-bit integer division if possible, it's significantly faster even than the "simple" case of `div r64`.